# DLNA/Multicast over vpn (Plex)

Tags: openvpn, wan, dlna, plex

I'm not a networking pro and I've been trying to get this to work for the last couple of days.

Infrastructure:

Home:

- vdsl 100/40, fritzbox 7490
- ip range: 192.168.100.0/24
- linux server which runs Plex Media Server(PMS) (ifs: eth0, tun0)

Remote location:

- openwrt box (dlink dir 825)

  - (ifs: br-lan, br-wan, eth0(lan), eth1(wan), wlan0/1, tun0)
- ip range: 192.168.178.0/24

Those two are connected via an OpenVPN tun0 (10.8.0.0/24)

Basically I want to use the PMS over the internet, the LG TV should see the DLNA service and so on.

I've tried to use igmpproxy with various configurations - but none seemed to work

Home igmpproxy (running on the PMS box):

```
quickleave 
phyint eth0 upstream ratelimit 0 threshold 1 
    altnet 192.168.100.0/24 
phyint tun0 downstream ratelimit 0 threshold 1
```

Remote igmpproxy:

```
quickleave 
phyint tun0 upstream ratelimit 0 threshold 1 
    altnet 10.8.0.0/24 
    altnet 192.168.100.0/24 
phyint br-lan downstream ratelimit 0 threshold 1
```

Anyone got this to work before or has any tipps?

edit: changed ip range of home

Answer (score 0):

```
ip range: 192.168.178.0/24
ip range: 192.168.178.0/24
```

Remote devices can't tell whether 192.168.178.10 is local to it or on the other network. You have to use different IP spaces on local and remote. Its best to set the network housing your VPN server to something that won't collide when you're elsewhere, so don't use 192.168.0/.1 or 10.0.0. etc.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the ip range of "home" to 192.168.100.0/24
Home igmp:
`quickleave

phyint eth0 upstream  ratelimit 0  threshold 1
        altnet 192.168.100.0/24
phyint tun0 downstream  ratelimit 0  threshold 1
`

remote igmp:
`quickleave

phyint tun0 upstream ratelimit 0 threshold 1
        altnet 10.8.0.0/24
        altnet 192.168.100.0/24

phyint br-lan downstream ratelimit 0 threshold 1
`
Are thos the right altnet ranges? I'm still getting no dlna here

Comment: Oh I forgot to include that, getting BCasts to work over a VPN is, IMO, a nightmare. The best way to solve that is to use a bridged ethernet VPN but thats complicated to deploy. If its plex you want the client app will allow you to enter the server IP in manually, thats how I use mine over OpenVPN.